# SQLAlchemy, Can you get out a specific entitiy's column value in one single query (using column.name)?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Im using Python 3 and SQLAlchemy and my question is if there is a way I can get out a specific entitiy's(character in my case) column value in one single query (maybe using column.name)?

Right now there is a way for me doing this.

```
character = session.query(Character).filter_by(id=1).first()
print(character.level)
>>> 10
```

What I want do be able to do is something like this where I dont know which column value I want:

```
character = session.query(Character).filter_by(id=1).first()
for i, column in enumerate(character.__table__.columns):
    if i == 3:
        #Not sure about this query
        someColumnValue = session.query(character).load_only(column.name)
        # Lets say its the level column
        someColumnValue += 1
        session.commit()
        #And the character.level will now be 10 + 1 stored in the database
        print(someColumnValue)
>>> 11
```

Maybe there is now way to do this or maybe there is a smarter way for me to get my result, maybe iterating in another way or so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for sqlalchemy columns iterate have a look at [Mapper.attrs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.attrs)

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
mapper = inspect(Character)
for column in mapper.attrs:
    print column.key
```

Comment: Tried that one, the thing is that I need to access the column value of a specific entity, not the name/key. Its another way to iterate the column names though. Can mapper.attrs give out the column.value and can you filter the character by id?